# Error "from keyword not found where expected" when executing a stored procedure oracle

Tags: oracle11g, toad

I have the following store procedure i am getting an error "from keyword not found where expected" . Is there any issue with paramater p_usr_tz usage in the select query ?

I have set p_usr_tz  to 'Europe/London' and p_wi_id to 48127808

```
PROCEDURE getworkitembyid (p_wi_id IN NUMBER,p_usr_tz IN VARCHAR2
    , workitem OUT prvdr_rec  )
   AS
   BEGIN
      OPEN workitem FOR
         SELECT wi.id wi_id
              , wi.type_name
              , wi.status
              , wi.priority
              , wi.crt_usr_id
              , crt_usr.name crt_name
              , crt_usr.pass crt_pass
              , crt_usr.first_name crt_first_name
              , crt_usr.last_name crt_last_name
              , crt_usr.email crt_email
              , from_tz (cast ( (wi.crt_tm) as timestamp), 'America/New_York') at time zone p_usr_tz crt_tm
              , wi.updt_usr_id
              , updt_usr.name updt_name
              , updt_usr.pass updt_pass
              , updt_usr.first_name updt_first_name
              , updt_usr.last_name updt_last_name
              , updt_usr.email updt_email
              , from_tz (cast ( (wi.updt_tm) as timestamp), 'America/New_York') at time zone p_usr_tz updt_tm
              , wi.lock_usr_id
              , lock_usr.name lock_name
              , lock_usr.pass lock_pass
              , lock_usr.first_name lock_first_name
              , lock_usr.last_name lock_last_name
              , lock_usr.email lock_email
              , wi.lock_tm
              , queue.id queue_id
              , queue.name
              , queue.TYPE
              , queue_wi.state
              , queue_wi.queue_entry_tm
           FROM wi
                INNER JOIN sec_usr crt_usr
                   ON wi.crt_usr_id = crt_usr.id
                INNER JOIN sec_usr updt_usr
                   ON wi.updt_usr_id = updt_usr.id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sec_usr lock_usr
                   ON wi.lock_usr_id = lock_usr.id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN queue_wi
                   ON wi.id = queue_wi.wi_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN queue
                   ON queue_wi.queue_id = queue.id
          WHERE wi.id = p_wi_id;
   END getworkitembyid;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions007.htm#SQLRF00401

Despite not being very clear from the Oracle doc, it appears that the timezone in the `AT TIME ZONE` clause cannot be a bind variable; it has to be a literal or an expression.

One possible solution, not a pretty one, though, would be to use native dynamic SQL and making the `P_USR_TZ` variable value "hardcoded" in the `SELECT`, i.e.

```
SQL> 
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE example_procedure
  3      ( p_some_date_value IN DATE
  4      , p_usr_tz          IN VARCHAR2
  5      , workitem          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
  6  AS
  7  BEGIN
  8      OPEN workitem FOR q'{
  9          SELECT :p_some_date_value AS original_date_value
 10           , from_tz (cast ( (:p_some_date_value) as timestamp), 'America/New_York') at time zone '}'||p_usr_tz||q'{' AS timezone_changed_date_value
 11          FROM dual
 12      }' USING
 13          IN p_some_date_value,
 14          IN p_some_date_value
 15      ;
 16  END example_procedure;
 17  /

Procedure created.

SQL> 
SQL> VAR example_cursor REFCURSOR;
SQL> 
SQL> EXEC example_procedure(sysdate, 'Europe/London', :example_cursor);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> COL original_date_value FORMAT A30
SQL> COL timezone_changed_date_value FORMAT A45
SQL> 
SQL> PRINT :example_cursor;

ORIGINAL_DATE_VALUE            TIMEZONE_CHANGED_DATE_VALUE                      
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------    
04.06.14                       04.06.14 17:32:07,000000 EUROPE/LONDON
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately it didnt work it says time zone not found and also i didnt understand why there are braces and the character q in the timezone statement

Comment: The braces and the Q are there because of this:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218

Comment: And what do you mean by "It didn't work" ? Works very well for me, see the updated answer.

Comment: May be in toad i guess its not working though i have got a work around i enclosed the parameter p_usr_tz in braces and it worked,thanks for writing back anyways

Comment: Please, post your solution here. I don't get what you mean by "enclosed the parameter p_usr_tz in braces".